# Vertex in Java using JUNG library

Tags: java, jung, vertex

I am trying to use the JUNG library to visualise a basic graph with vertices and edges. Using the example code on the website, I have the following:

```
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.DirectedSparseGraph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.UndirectedSparseGraph;
import java.util.*;

public class GraphTest {

    public GraphTest(){        
        Graph g = new DirectedSparseGraph();
        Vertex v1 = (Vertex) g.addVertex(new DirectedSparseVertex());
    Vertex v2 = (Vertex) g.addVertex(new DirectedSparseVertex());
    }
```

However, "Vertex" is underlined in red and Netbeans is telling me it cannot find symbol. I tried importing what Netbeans suggested but to no avail, and now I believe that Vertex is actually native to Java. I've no idea where I'm going wrong but I think it's an elementary error that is escaping me.

Answer (score 1):

Check the return type of `addVertex` the JavaDoc for [DirectedSparseGraph#addVertex](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/DirectedSparseGraph.html#addVertex%28V%29)  suggests that the function returns a boolean not a `Vertex` Jung 1.XX did have a method that returned an `ArchetypeVertex` that could be downcast to a `Vertex`.  I think you nay be trying to get an example from version 1 working with version 2 but it's not backwards compatiable and this is causing a build error.

Comment: This is taken directly from the JUNG website, though. The problem is that per se, it's that Netbeans isn't recognising Vertex as a class at all.

Comment: Can you link to the example please?

Comment: If an example using JUNG 1.x (which this is) is still on the JUNG website, please link to it.  There should be no such examples.

Comment: @JoshuaO'Madadhain [link](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/manual.html#create) was the only reference I could find so he may be working from the manual. I was basing this answer on addVertex returning a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Jung uses generic types, it doesn't define a Vertex type.

What do you plan to put into your graph?

Assuming you want Strings for your vertex and integers for your edges, your code should look something like

```
Graph<String,Integer> g = new DirectedSparseGraph<String,Intger>();
g.addVertex("foo"); // return type is just a boolean indicating if the vertex was already in graph
g.addVertex("bar");
```

Which will give you a graph with two unconnected vertices.

Comment: hi Henry, nice answer, but where do I get SparseVertex in this example code: Vertex v1 = new SparseVertex(); ?

Comment: How does Edge work? How can I define a Edge? Isnt there a basic class I can derive from?

Comment: How can I output that Graph into a Panel?

Comment: @ErdincAy Early versions of Jung provided vertex types such as SparseVertex. Modern versions use generics as I have shown and do not require you to subclass anything. I suggest you ask about outputting to a panel in a new question - however you might wish to read the Jung documentation first. http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html

Comment: my aim is to use this library on android, i am not sure if JUNG in a newer version that uses generics will be usable on android then ...